# If $(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2$ is a solution of $(x^2-dy^2)^2=1$ with minimal $x$ then $a^2-db^2=-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I need help with the following question:

> If $d\in\mathbb N$ such as the equation $x^2-dy^2=-1$ has an integer solution. If $(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2$ is a solution of $(x^2-dy^2)^2=1$ with minimal $x$ (for any other solution $(x,y)$, $a\le x$). Prove that $a^2-db^2=-1$.

I proved that if $(e,f),(g,h) \in \mathbb N$ are solution of $(x^2-dy^2)^2=1$ then $e+f\sqrt d<g+h\sqrt d$ iff $e<g$.

It is pretty obvious to see that if $a^2-db^2\neq-1$ then $a^2-db^2=1$.

I know it can help with the question but I can't understand how.

Comment: The closely related post of [Fundamental solutions of the positive Pell Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2425537/602049) may be of interest to you as the question states an explicit form of the fundamental solution of the positive Pell equation in terms of that of the negative Pell equation.

Answer (score 1):

let the smallest solution to positive Pell be $u^2 - d v^2 = 1,$ with integers $u,v > 0.$

This defines an automorphism of the quadratic form, if $p^2 - d q^2 = T$ with $p,q>0$ integers, there is a larger expression for $T$ using
$$ (p,q)  \mapsto (up + dvq, vp + u q).  $$
In turn, when $p,q>0$ are not too small, there is a smaller positive expression using
$$ (p,q)  \mapsto (up - dvq, -vp + u q).  $$

Next, take $r^2 - d s^2 = -1$  with positive $r,s.$   Keep reducing by $ (r,s)  \mapsto (ur - dvs, -vr + u s)  $  until you arrive at a final
$$ x^2 - d y^2 = -1  $$
with $x,y > 0$  BUT
$$ \color{red}{ ux-dvy \leq 0 \; \; \; \mbox{OR} \;\;\; -vx +uy \leq 0.}  $$
Now, the conditions $$ \frac{x}{y} < \sqrt d < \frac{u}{v} $$
tell us that $vx< uy$ always, so the second condition is false. It must be the first condition that holds for our "fundamental negative Pell" solution $(x,y).$
That is,
$$ ux \leq dvy. $$
All quantities are positive, we are allowed to square both sides.
$$ u^2 x^2 \leq d^2 v^2 y^2 = (dv^2)(dy^2) $$
$$ u^2 x^2 \leq (u^2-1)(x^2 + 1)  $$
$$  u^2 x^2 \leq u^2 x^2 - x^2 + u^2 - 1  $$
$$  0 \leq -x^2 + u^2 - 1  $$
$$  x^2 \leq u^2 - 1 < u^2  $$
$$ x^2 < u^2 $$
Both are positive,
$$   x < u  $$
The smallest $x$ value for negative Pell (when such a thing exists) is smaller than the smallest $x$ value for positive Pell.

Who Knew?